# Line breaks Django string

Tags: python, django, django-views

Is there a way to display line breaks in a rendered Django string?

```
contact_message = "Name: %s | Email: %s" % (
        form_name,
        form_email,
    )
```

For example, the code above currently prints as:

```
Name: <rendered name> | Email: <rendered email>
```

Is there a way to make it print like this:

```
Name: <rendered name>
Email: <rendered email>
```

I will be using the send_mail function, so I am hoping to make the readability more visually appealing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When sending mail, a simple `\n` should be enough:

```
contact_message = "Name: %s\nEmail: %s" % (
    form_name,
    form_email,
)
```

This won't work in HTML, there you need HTML tags and then you have to mark the string as safe: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.safestring

Answer (score 1):

if you want just to have a new line you can just do it with:

```
contact_message = "Name: %s \n Email: %s" % (
        form_name,
        form_email,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

\n is the way to go in django!

Comment: I appreciate the response. Thank you!